# Axios post request in react-native app

Tags: http, post, axios, react-native

I'm using ***axios*** in my react-native app, but I can't make any ***POST*** request in android simulator/device. It always return `400 Bad Request` from the server.

I've tried to set `Content-Type: application/json` on headers but it didn't work as well.

on postman the request works as expected.

here's the request config object:

[image: request config object]

Comment: Show some code. It's impossible to help if people can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, [**400 Bad Request**](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-a-400-bad-request-error-2617988) error means that the request you sent to the website server was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.

I think there maybe problems on your request like as wrong URL or params or header format...

PS. Axios post methods syntax is as follows:

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

You can test any axios method [here](https://npm.runkit.com/axios) and put it into your code base after it works.

Comment: I got it, but it works on swagger and postman as well, I can't figure out what I'm missing in react.

here's successfully curl request from swagger:  
  
`curl -X POST "https://reginato-sdpapi.azurewebsites.net/api/autenticacao/token" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"email\": \"test@test.com\", \"password\": \"password\"}"`

Comment: when I try it with Postman, I got error: Web App-Unavailable
Can you post the postman result?